# Can I move the minimap to the main screen?

Tags: mario-kart-8

It took like forever to figure out where I can find the minimap in MK8, and now that I found it it's still really annoying always having to look down when I want to know where the other characters are.

Is there a way to Move the Minimap from the gamepad to the Main screen? And if yes: How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there is no way to get this up the television. So if you're holding the gamepad during a split screen game, you have an advantage.